# Cross Compilation Building Linux App on Windows

Tags: windows, pthreads

I have a build that builds a native app on linux. That build links in the pthread library and one or two others.

I am porting the build to be cross compilation build on Windows.

How do I include such libraries in this build? Is there an URL where I can download the library and then add it to my build? Or should I locate it on linux platform and copy it across?

Thanks

Comment: Are you asking how to build an app that will run on Gnu/Linux, using MS-Windows. OR are you asking how to port a Gnu/Linux app to MS-Windows? (edit question to make clearer)

Comment: What he meant: An app that already runs on Linux, and how that app will also run on Windows with the least change when compiling (e.g: some flag changes at most).

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. To clarify :

 I have a target. That target runs linux. On that target I build an app for that very target. That build links in libraries such as pthread etc.. 

I now need to port that build to windows, making the build a cross compilation. I can install the correct cross compiler however I am unsure how to address libraries like pthread that are part of the linux system. The target is still the original linux system. It is only the build that is being done on Windows.

Comment: Actually if the library is an .so , then It may not need to be available in the build process on the windows machine. Is this correct?  Some extra information is that the target is an embedded system, and I am being tasked to port the build to windows.

Comment: Thanks. I did consider that it was more of an embedded systems question albeit with the target running linux. I will post the question on stack overflow. Do I delete the question on this site ?